# Реализовать хранение счет в банке

Tags: java, многопоточность

Конечно такого не будет, но как лучше всего можно сделать хранение счета в банке без использования БД только RAM в многопоточной среде, я так понимаю можно использовать AtomicInteger для хранения суммы, и гарантируется точное списание. Но как можно обеспечить атомарность, чтобы к примеру у одного пользователя списалось и записалось к второму следуя принципу согласованности  и устойчивости. Хочется как в БД коммит был согласованный.

```
void process(Account from, Account to, int sum) {
    AtomicInteger fromAtomicInteger = from.getAmount();
    AtomicInteger toAtomicInteger = to.getAmount();
    toAtomicInteger.addAndGet(sum);
    // что если выключится компьютер, допустим данные сохраняется после выключения
    fromAtomicInteger.addAndGet(-sum);
}
```

Comment: не понимаю вопроса. в теле вопроса одно, а в коде под комментарием другое. что именно нужно делать?

Comment: Вы же сами понимаете, что такое невозможно?

Comment: @RomanC Почему невозможно? А как по-вашему работают базы данных?

Comment: @Zergatul Невозможно, чтобы данные сохранились в ОЗУ после выключения компьютера.

Comment: @StasDorozhko Автор описывает теоретическую ситуацию, все что он пишет в ОЗУ, само сохранится куда-то при выключении. Если он начнет писать в файл, получится своя база данных.

Comment: Это длинная история. Есть множество баз данных и все они хранят информацию в виде файлов с определённой структурой. Данна структура хранится в заголовке, которая хранит метаданные. База данных это сложное приложение работающее как сервер который принимает запросы по определенному протоколу. Базы данных также предоставляют сагкцианированный доступ с учётной записью. Некоторые банки так делают когда регистрируют своих пользователей, то дают доступ к определённым данным. Собственно говоря, Я начинал работать с ДБ3,  поэтому не совсем помню базы данных, которые можно было собирать самому.@zergatul

Comment: @Zergatul Любая постоянная память является своего рода базой данных. В этом и видится противоречие.

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, Вы хотите обойтись без СУБД (написать свой вариант) либо Вы хотите обойтись вообще без постоянной памяти (строго ОЗУ)? Второй вариант видится невозможным.

Comment: Да мне интересно, как обеспечить согласованность и атомарность как в БД.

Comment: Согласованность и устойчивость

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... что если выключится компьютер, допустим данные сохраняется после выключения

Чтобы обеспечить [устойчивость](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID#Durability_%E2%80%94_%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) «как в СУБД» нужно вводить в программу понятие транзакции, хранить информацию о транзакциях в постоянной памяти (вести журнал транзакций), реализовывать логику отката/повторного выполнения.

Вариант решения: хранить блокировку в постоянной памяти. Далее псевдокод:

```
//создаем запись в журнале транзакций,
//которая хранится в постоянном хранилище:
//в базе данных, файловой системе и т.п.
Transaction transaction = bank.createTransaction(from, to);
...
//выполняем операции
...
//отмечаем транзакцию как завершенную
transaction.finish();
```

для простоты опустил обработку исключений.

Если выключится компьютер, то при следующем запуске приложение прочитает из журнала записи о незавершенных транзакциях и обработает их по мере необходимости: либо откатит, либо доведет до конца, либо сообщит пользователю о проблемах в данных.

Также для корректной работы приведенного кода потребуется реализовать надежную [изоляцию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID#Isolation_%E2%80%94_%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) транзакций. Например после этой строки:

```
toAtomicInteger.addAndGet(sum);
```

может выполнится другая транзакция, которая переведет деньги с измененного счета `to` на третий счет и успешно завершится. Если после этого произойдет ошибка, то безболезненно откатить текущую транзакцию уже не получится. Избежать подобного рода ошибок можно [блокировкой](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) счетов на время операции. Соответственно, такие блокировки также должны храниться в постоянной памяти.

СУБД как правило предоставляют встроенные механизмы управления транзакциями.

Comment: Если это простой вопрос, как достигается согласованность, на техническом уровне, когда две базы должны закомитить данные, одна БД посылает сообщение что я готов и ждет пока второй ответит, вторая бд ответила но откуда уверенность что первая БД  получила ответ от второго, единственное что я думаю так это таймер какой то вставлять, но так теряется производительность?

Comment: @AlexanderBelov Это не простой вопрос. Обеспечение производительности вместе с изоляцией это краеугольный камень всей индустрии СУБД.

Comment: @AlexanderBelov Ваш новый пример (взаимодействие между двумя удаленными БД) сильно отличается от вопроса (восстановление транзакции при отключении). Гарантированная доставка сообщений: отдельная тема, заслуживающая отдельного рассмотрения. Можете почитать про [механизм в TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Reliable_transmission) либо задать отдельный вопрос.

Comment: ок, думал вдруг там в два слова можно сказать)

Comment: @AlexanderBelov Спасибо за отметку! Рад был чем-то помочь.